# Integrating with SAGE PRO ERP software

Tags: enterprise

Can anyone provide me with a high-level description of what the SAGE PRO erp SDK is like (XML? ODBC? etc..)

Also, any experience with the SAGE "developer program" would be welcome (http://www.sagebusinessworks.com/partners/become-dev-partner.aspx)

Comment: I don't know if the ERP version was pro, but it used the Pervasive database & there is an ODBC driver for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently working with SAGE Pro Series 7.2.  Can't speak for the developer program but I can speak for the VAR training that they used to give.  You'll get a basic overview of the system design, and some of the design decisions they made, and how they fit together.  If you're familiar with their older products and want to "move up", then it's probably worth your time.  Please note that was about 3 years ago.

I don't have a SDK, but I do have a license for on-site source and a licensed copy of VFP 8.  The PDF documentation I have is adequate and covers what you need to know for modifying the system.

The only roadblock in the development process has been the insistence of ACCPAC/Sage that the go_SQL object be closed-source, i.e. you can't debug anything that steps into the object, so all of your database calls tend to be opaque.  Otherwise it's business as usual.

ODBC can be done with the FoxPro drivers for Windows XP (you know you have the right ones when they show 6.x as the version number in the ODBC admin panel).  Be sure to install the ODBC driver first, *then install the OLE DB provider over the top of it*.  It appears that the second installation fixes a subtle bug that causes deleted records to appear when they are not wanted, although I don't know why at this point in time.  It is however 100% confirmed as a fix for the problem.

When you are setting up your ODBC connection, use the DBC and not "free tables".  That should give you access to every table in the installation.  Note that some programs that use the ODBC driver to obtain a list of tables will not return anything more than a blank list; this is a problem in the ODBC driver and you will have to work around it.